# Bypassing [authorize] in controller gives forbidden in xUnit test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I want to bypass [authorize] while testing API in xUnit project in Asp.net Core 2.2.

I have taken reference from  [this](https://github.com/jackowild/aspnetcore-bypassing-authentication) project but I am unable to bypass the [authorize] and got forbidden response.

I am stuck in below code snippet:

```
 public static class TestAuthenticationExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddTestAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<TestAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        var retval = builder.AddScheme<TestAuthenticationOptions, TestAuthenticationHandler>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "password", configureOptions);
        return retval;
    }
}
public class TestAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public virtual ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; } = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
       {
            new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
       }, "test");
    }
```

Comment: have you set the roles properly?

Comment: @CallumLinington Can you please provide me code snippet?

Comment: Urmm, it doesn't quite work that way around - you need to provide the code snippets first - so we can say what is wrong with it - I'm just stabbing in the dark due to a lack of detail on your part.

Comment: @CallumLinington I have provided the snippet

Comment: we need to see the controller you're trying to access

Comment: If you bypass the authorization, you're not actually testing anything. The action(s) could function completely differently depending on whether they're authorized or not. A test is only valid if you're dealing with circumstances as close to reality as possible. You should also not be unit testing controllers. Your API endpoints should be integration tested. If you're doing work that you want to independently test, factor that out into a class or classes that your actions can then utilize. Then, you can easily unit test the helper class(es).